# How to put the Mongodb results into an array?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection inside my database MongoDB:

```
/*Order:*/
{
item: 'banana',
price: '2$',
order_type: INTERNATIONAL // There are 2 types: INTERNATIONAL and MAINLAND
}
```

I do a group stage to group out all the orders with type INTERNATIONAL and MAINLAND then count the total number of each type of order.

```
db.getCollection('get_card_request').aggregate([
    {$group: {
        _id: '$order_type',
        nbOfOrders: {$sum: 1}    
    }}
])
```

The results I received is like this:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "MAINLAND",
    "nbOfOrder" : 3.0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "INTERNATIONAL",
    "nbOfOrder" : 2.0
}
```

I want to put the results after the group stage inside an array but I don't know how to. I want to have a result like this:

```
{
orderTypeCount: [
{
    "_id" : "MAINLAND",
    "nbOfOrder" : 3.0
},
{
    "_id" : "INTERNATIONAL",
    "nbOfOrder" : 2.0
}
],
... // the other fields
}
```

Comment: Were you able to try the answer? Could you approve/upvote/both if it was helpful?

Answer (score 0):

[play](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9pfeXiFmqkG)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$order_type",
      nbOfOrders: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "orderTypeCount": {
        "$push": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "_id": 0
    }
  }
])
```

I pushed all the data from previous pipeline to an array variable.